# Key / Value persistence supported by Android AND Java

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, persistence

I'm writing code that could be run on Java platform or Android platform. This is the same code for the 2 platforms. I would like to add a persitence feature to save some settings. If it targeting only Android, I would use shared prefs, but I can't use it because this is not compatible with java standard platform.

Do you have an idea to have a solution that can be ran on Android and Java ?
Or maybe a way to made a sort of switch depending of the platform ?

Comment: as usual ... interface + inject implementation with IoC(DI)

Comment: How to know the current platform to inject the right implementation ?

Comment: You know that obviously you cannot run the same assembly on java se and Android? You know that you have at least different bootstrap for both platform (main and some starting Activity) you can always setup ioc container there..

Comment: It's a library, today the same jar file is embedded in an Android app or a Java app